# Difficulty authenticating with Python package Requests

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm trying to use requests to access an API.  The API has a key, secret key, user name, and password.  When reviewing the requests documentation, I see an option for authenticating with just a username and password or with an API key, API secret key, user authentication token, and user authentication token secret. When I try using HttpBasicAuth I get a 404 status code. Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: We'll need to see documentation about the API you're trying to access, or sample code in another language (e.g. a curl command) which works.

Comment: Can you add the relevant python code?